# awk filter out CSV file content based on condition on a column

Tags: awk

I am trying to filter out content in CSV file based on condition on 2nd column.

Example :

**myfile.csv:**

```
A,2,Z
C,1,B
D,9,X
BB,3,NN
DD,8,PP
WA,10,QR
```

**exclude.list**

```
2
9
8
```

**desired output file**

```
C,1,B
BB,3,NN
WA,10,QR
```

If i wanted to exclude `2` , i could use :  `awk -F',' ' $2!="2"  {print }' myfile.csv`. I am trying to figure how to iterate over exclude.list file to exclude all values in the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***1st Solution (preferred):*** Following `awk` may help you.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next} !($2 in a)' exclude.list  FS="," myfile.csv
```

***2nd Solution (Comprehensive):*** Adding one more `awk` by changing Input_file(s) sequence of reading, though first solution is more preferable I am adding this to cover all possibilities of solutions :)

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[$2]=$0;
  if(!b[$2]++){  c[++i]=$2  };
  next}
($1 in a)     {  delete a[$1]}
END{
  for(j=1;j<=i;j++){
    if(a[c[j]]){print a[c[j]]}
}}
' FS="," myfile.csv FS=" " exclude.list
```

Comment: @JamesBrown, thanks sir, appreciation from you, you made my day. Learning from you all experts sir :) cheers